# How to search Google for business name and return address using VBA, Excel

Tags: vba, excel, google-maps

So I have a list of business names in excel starting in cell A2, going down to A3, A4, and so on. What I need to do is retrieve the address for these businesses and return the address in the cell next to it (B2, B3, B4 ...).

I have thousands of business names so I do not want to have to do this manually. Is there a way of searching the web / Google/Bing maps for the business and returning the respective address using VBA. If not, is there any other method I could use to populate my Excel table?

Comment: I'd start by reading the [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview).

Comment: This question, in many forms, has been asked myriad times. Please search Google and/or SO itself for such methods.  You should find some code pretty quickly, so use that and when you get stuck, you can come ask for specific questions regarding it.  In the end, yes there's a way.

Comment: I have done a lot of research before posting on here, and have found nothing that works for me! Was just asking a question to see if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are going to do with this data, Bing Maps may not be an option as the [terms of use](https://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html) has the following restriction:

> **3.2** (h)Use Content that consists of points of interest data to generate sales leads information in the form of ASCII or other text-formatted lists of category-specific business listings which (i) include complete mailing address for each business; and (ii) contain a substantial portion of such listings for a particular country, city, state or zip code region.

I wouldn't be surprised if Google Maps has a similar restriction.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

[image]

```
Sub myTest()
    Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60
    Dim domDoc As DOMDocument60
    Dim domDoc2 As DOMDocument60
    Dim placeID As String
    Dim query As String
    Dim nodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim node As IXMLDOMNode

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:A5")

    For Each cell In rng

    'you have to replace spaces with +
    query = cell.Value

    'You must acquire a google api key and enter it here
    Dim googleKey As String
    googleKey = "your_specific_key_goes_here" 'your api key here

    'Send a "GET" request for place/textsearch
    Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60

    xhrRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?" & _
        "query=" & query & "&key=" & googleKey, False
    xhrRequest.send

    'Save the response into a document
    Set domDoc = New DOMDocument60
    domDoc.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText

    'Find the first node that is called "place_id" and is the child of the "result" node
    placeID = domDoc.SelectSingleNode("//result/place_id").Text

    'recycling objects (could just use new ones)
    Set domDoc = Nothing
    Set xhrRequest = Nothing

    'Send a "GET" request for place/details
    Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60
    xhrRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" & placeID & _
    "&key=" & googleKey, False
    xhrRequest.send

    'Save the response into a document
    Set domDoc = New DOMDocument60
    domDoc.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText

    Dim output As String
    Dim s As String

    'hacky way to get postal code, you might want to rewrite this after learning more
    Set nodes = domDoc.SelectNodes("//result/address_component/type")
    For Each node In nodes
        s = node.Text
        If s = "street_number" Then
            'this is bad, you should search for "long_name", what i did here was assume that "long_name was the first child"
            'output = vbNewLine & "Postal Code: " & node.ParentNode.FirstChild.Text
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Address: " & node.ParentNode.FirstChild.Text
        End If

        If s = "postal_code" Then
            'this is bad, you should search for "long_name", what i did here was assume that "long_name was the first child"
            'output = vbNewLine & "Postal Code: " & node.ParentNode.FirstChild.Text
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Postal Code: " & node.ParentNode.FirstChild.Text
        End If
    Next node

    Next cell
    'output
    'MsgBox "Formatted Address: " & domDoc.SelectSingleNode("//result/formatted_address").Text & output
End Sub
```

Make sure you get your own Google API Key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Just go to the link above and click the button that says 'GET A KEY'.